# Why does my code do assignments that I didn't write?

Tags: c, arrays

my array called tablero[2][2] is empty. When I try to assign a number in its [0][2] or [1][2] position, the [1][0] and the [2][0] positions are asigned too. I dont know why this happens

```
  void introducir_ficha(){
        int valido = 0;
        int pos_x, pos_y;
        while(valido == 0){
            printf("Introduce la posicion que quieres para la ficha \n");
            scanf("%d",&pos_x);
            printf("\n");
            scanf("%d",&pos_y);
            if(pos_x > 2 || pos_y > 2){
                printf("La posicion no es valida... \n");
            }else{
                valido = comprobar_hueco(pos_x, pos_y);
//comprobar_hueco just returns if this position is empty or not
                if(valido == 0){
                    printf("La posicion no es valida... \n");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Posiciones %d %d \n",pos_x,pos_y);
        tablero[pos_x][pos_y] = 1;
    }
```

I hope u can help me.

Comment: What are `i` and `j`?....

Comment: fixed, I misspeled it

Comment: Is your array 2x2? If so, you shouldn't be assigning as if it's 3x3.

Comment: Waht happens if you enter `-42`?

Comment: @alk thats why the function `comprobar_hueco(pos_x, pos_y)`exists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tablero[2][2]` is a 2 by 2 array. Thus the four elements are [0][0], [0][1], [1][0], and [1][1]. There are no [0][2] or [1][2] elements.

If you try to use an index of 2, it will exceed the bounds of the row or column, and possibly wrap into the next row/column, or it will access memory outside the array entirely and may crash the program.

To use element indices from 0 to 2, you want a 3 by 3 array.

Comment: but if tablero is [2][2] doesnt it have 3 spaces? 0,1,2?

Comment: No, if you define your table like `int array[2][2]` then that's a 2x2 array. Only indices up to 0 and 1 exist.

Comment: @Patxiku: OT: What you call "*spaces*" is called "*elements*".

Comment: @Patxiku No. The right indexing would be [0][0],[0][1],[1][0] and [1][1]

Comment: @Patxiku No. By typing [2], you define an array with size of [2] which means you have 2 elements in that array. Array indices start from [0]. So [0] and [1] will be corresponding indices. As for your two-dimensional array "tablero", Boann made the necessary explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that acceptable indexes for your array are in the range [0, 1]. Arrays are placed in memory row by row. So your array will have representation in the memory as

```
tablero[0][0] tablero[0][1]
tablero[1][0] tablero[1][1]
```

When you try to access an element of the array using indexes [0][2] the compiler calculates the addres as 0 * sizeof( int[2] ) + 2 * sizeof( int ) (provided that the element type of the arrray is int). As the result it will calculate the address of the element that corresponds to indexes [1][0]